# Yii2 got Error Message

Tags: yii2

anyone who can help me to fix this problem.....i got this error after i update my composer at my yii2 application..
[image]

also i got error messsage this:

```
 * @return array the path directory and the URL that the asset is published as.
 * @throws InvalidParamException if the asset to be published does not exist.
 */
protected function publishDirectory($src, $options)
{
    $dir = $this->hash($src);
    $dstDir = $this->basePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir;
    if ($this->linkAssets) {
        if (!is_dir($dstDir)) {
            symlink($src, $dstDir);
        }
    } elseif (!empty($options['forceCopy']) || ($this->forceCopy && !isset($options['forceCopy'])) || !is_dir($dstDir)) {
        $opts = array_merge(
            $options,
            [
                'dirMode' => $this->dirMode,
                'fileMode' => $this->fileMode,
            ]
        );
```

My 2nd problem after i run composer diagnose...i got message:
checking composer.json: FAIL..
actually what the problem of this...

Answer (score 1):

Set linkAssets to false here:

https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit/blob/master/common/config/web.php#L6

It is a common problem about php `symlink()` function in Windows systems. There are many posts around the web about it

Comment: what the path to set linkAssets

Comment: If you are coding in frontend then
frontend/config/main.php if backend then backend/config/main.php

Comment: one of my friend got this error same in windows OS. and i googled and found this solution. so i dont know much about this error. btw if you found my answer useful pls mark as accept so other people get help from this. thanks cheers.